# Error when updating my dependencies in React

Tags: npm

I just added some code to my dependencies list in my package.json file. I ran NPM update --save and I am getting this error

npm ERR! code 128
npm ERR! An unknown git error occurred
npm ERR! command git --no-replace-objects ls-remote ssh://git@github.com/process/browser.git
npm ERR! git@github.com: Permission denied (publickey).npm ERR! fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Please make sure you have the correct access rights
npm ERR! and the repository exists.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in: